# On click only apply class to element clicked, not all elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of filters which are in accordions. When the user clicks on one of the filter headings, I just want to show that elements fitlers. My issue is that when I click on an element header to show the filters, all the other classes change too.

```
            $('.filter-group__title').on('click', function () {
                $(".glyphicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-minus glyphicon-plus");
            });
```

Comment: Well I don't know your HTML structure. Could you post that as well?

Answer (score 1):

You should be referring the parent with "this"

```
$('.filter-group__title').on('click', function () {
    $(this).find(".glyphicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-minus glyphicon-plus");
});
```

Comment: Logic solution, however I asked for the HTML structure because maybe glyphicon is a direct child of filter group title. (upvoted though)